# Efficiency of a cyclic processes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, heat-engine

Is there a specific formula for solving the efficiency of a cyclic process in pV diagram?

I have this diagram of a diatomic ideal gas cyclic process, where ${p} = 4{p_0}$ and ${V} = 4{V_0}$

[image]

The work that I got is ${W} = -9{p_0}{V_0}$ because of paths ${bc}$ and ${da}$ are isobaric.

But it asks for the efficiency of this cycle. Is there a formula for that or is it equal to heat engines?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The general equation for the efficiency, $\eta$,  for any heat engine cycle is

$$\eta=\frac{W_{NET}}{Q_{IN}}$$

You should be able to take it from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is Qin equal to 12poVo??

Comment: @mamab I don't even see how you got the  net work done. How can it be negative? It is the area under process b-c minus the area under process d-a

Comment: @mamab The net work done is the area enclosed by the cycle